# Database error doesn't get values inserted phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, database-connection

ctimings.html

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyle.css">
            //  <script type="text/javascript">
            //      function validate(form)
            //       { 
            //          if(document.myForm.sno.value == "")
            //          {
            //              alert("Please Complete Serial NUmber");
            //              return false;
            //          }
            //          if(document.myForm.ssign.value == "")
            //          {
            //              alert("Please Complete Signature");
            //              return false;
            //          }
            //          if(document.myForm.empName.value == "")
            //          {
            //              alert("Please Complete Employee Name");
            //              return false;
            //          }
            //          if(document.myForm.empSign.value == "")
            //          {
            //              alert("Please Complete Employee Signature");
            //              return false;
            //          }
            //          if(document.myForm.empCode.value == "")
            //          {
            //              alert("Please Complete Employee Code");
            //              return false;
            //          }
            //      }
            // </script>
            <title>Conference Room Timings</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form  action = "ctimings.php" method = "post" name = "myForm" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
                <legend>ADD DETAILS</legend>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Serial Number <input type = "int" name = "sno" size="20" class = "required" /></label><br/>
                    <label>Security Signature <input type = "text" name = "ssign" size="20" class = "required" /></label><br/>
                    <legend>Employee Details</legend>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Employee Name <input type = "text" name = "empName" size="20" class = "required" /></label><br/>
                        <label>Employee Signature <input type = "text" name = "empSign" size="20" class = "required"/></label><br/>
                        <label>Employee Code <input type = "int" name = "empCode" size="20" class = "required" /></label><br/>
                    </fieldset>


                    <legend>Date & Time</legend>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Date <input type = "int" name = "date" size="20" class = "required"/></label><br/>
                        <label>In - Time <input type = "int" name = "inTime" size="20" class = "required"/></label><br/>
                        <label>In - Time <input type = "int" name = "outTime" size="20" class = "required"/></label><br/>
                    </fieldset>

                    <legend>Usage</legend>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>
                        Phone Set Usage
                        <input type = "radio" name = "radio1" value = "YES" />
                        <input type = "radio" name = "radio1" value = "NO" /><br/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Projector Usage
                        <input type = "radio" name = "radio2" value = "YES" />
                        <input type = "radio" name = "radio2" value = "NO" /><br/>
                    </label>
                    </fieldset>

                    <input type = "submit" value = "SUBMIT" class = "" name =  "SUBMIT"/>

                </fieldset>

            </form>
        </body>


    </html>
```

ctimings.php

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php


        if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT']))
        {
            echo "pressed";
            $db_host = "localhost";
            $db_username = "root";
            $db_pass = "";
            $db_name = "ibm";
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","ibm");

        // Check connection
            $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            if (!$link) {
                die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Connection was OK';
            }
            $db_selected = mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
            if (!$db_selected) {
                die ('Can\'t use ibm : ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else
            { 
                echo "Database was OK!\n";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ctimings(sno,ssign,empName,empSign,date,intime,outtime,empCode,Proj.Use,Ph.Use) VALUES('$_POST[sno]','$_POST[ssign]','$_POST[empName]','$_POST[empSign]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[inTime]','$_POST[outTime]','$_POST[empCode]','$_POST[radio1]','$_POST[radio2]')";
            mysql_query($sql,$link);
            mysql_close($link);
          }
          else
            echo 'error';

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is a simple proceedure but i am not able to narrow down as to why is not the data being sent to the database as the phpmyadmin table "ctimings" shows that it has no record.After the submit button has been pressed it should post the data to the database but in vain.The database name and table names in the database are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is a Global Array you have to use it like this $_POST["field_name"];

Answer (score 0):

your query would be like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ctimings(sno,ssign,empName,empSign,date,intime,outtime,empCode,Proj.Use,Ph.Use) VALUES
('".$_POST[sno]."','".$_POST[ssign]."','".$_POST[empName]."','".$_POST[empSign]."','".$_POST[date]."',
 '".$_POST[inTime]."','".$_POST[outTime]."','".$_POST[empCode]."','".$_POST[radio1]."'
,'".$_POST[radio2]."')";
```

And you need to escape the post variables using **mysql_real_escape_string**

And main reason is due to **Proj.Use,Ph.Use** you are using insert into two tables at a time I think,

Answer (score 0):

Your sql string is incorrect, it needs to be;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ctimings(sno,ssign,empName,empSign,date,intime,outtime,empCode,Proj.Use,Ph.Use) VALUES('".$_POST[sno]."','".$_POST[ssign]."','".$_POST[empName]."','".$_POST[empSign]."','".$_POST[date]."','".$_POST[inTime]."','".$_POST[outTime]."','".$_POST[empCode]."','".$_POST[radio1]."','".$_POST[radio2]."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto the answers above, it might be an idea to sanitise your data.

```
$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
```